# $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \log\{\sin(x) \}=?$

Tags: calculus, limits

> How can I evaluate the right hand limit of $x \log\{\sin(x) \}$ as $x \to 0$ ; that is:
>   $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \log\{\sin(x) \}=?$$

My Approach:
Let $f(x)= x \log\{\sin(x) \}$
then, $f(0.1)=0.1 \log\{\sin(0.1) \}$ ; and we know for small values of $x : \quad  \sin(x) \approx x$
so, $f(0.1)=0.1 \log\{0.1 \}=0.1\log\{10^{-1} \}=-0.1$
similarly, $f(0.01)=0.01 \log\{\sin(0.01) \}=0.01 \log\{0.01 \}=0.01\log\{10^{-2} \}=-0.02$
so we conclude as $x \to 0$ , $f(x) \to 0$
Therefore , $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \log\{\sin(x) \}=0$

But, how can we find it in a systematic process? please help...

Comment: L'Hopital seems like a good fit.

Comment: please explain (if your approach is different from user284331)? @AndrewLi

Comment: That's exactly how I did it.

Comment: ok ,thanks for the comment @AndrewLi ;if you know any other process to solve this problem then kindly drop your valuable answer

Comment: @Suresh I suggest: don’t use l’Hospital, it’s the best way to not learn to deal with the limits, use standard limits or Taylor instead.

Comment: @Suresh Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \log(\sin(x)) &= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\log(\sin x)}{\frac1x}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^+} -\frac{x^2\cos x}{\sin x}\\
&= -\lim_{x \to 0^+ }x \cos x
\\&=0
\end{align}

Comment: How you get $$-\lim_{x \to 0^+ }x \cos x$$  from
   $$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} -\frac{x^2\cos x}{\sin x} $$ ?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x}{\sin x} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}x\log(\sin x)&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{\log(\sin x)}{1/x}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{(1/\sin x)\cos x}{-1/x^{2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}-\dfrac{x}{\sin x}\cdot(x\cos x)\\
&=-1\cdot 0\\
&=0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Using equivalents for small values of $x$
$$\sin(x) \sim x \implies \log(\sin(x)) \sim \log(x)\implies x\log(\sin(x)) \sim x\log(x)$$

Using Taylor series 
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)=x \left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}+O\left(x^4\right) \right)$$ 
$$\log(\sin(x))=\log(x)+\log\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}+O\left(x^4\right) \right)=\log(x)-\frac{x^2}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$x\log(\sin(x))=x\log(x)-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$

Comment: what is $O(x^5)$ ? please explain...

Comment: @Suresh. Landau big $O$ notation. Have a look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 0):

By standard limits

$$x \log(\sin(x))=\frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot \sin x\cdot \log(\sin(x))\to 1\cdot 0=0$$

Comment: @AndrewLi it's  a standard limit indeed with $ e^y=\frac1x \to \infty$ we have $$x\log x=-\frac{y}{e^y}\to 0$$

Comment: could you at least say that in your answer, or point to the different standard limits?

Comment: I’ve said “by standard limits” and it is really a base case. Anyway I’m always at disposal for any clarification.

Comment: @gimusi as x $\to$ 0 , $\log(\sin(x)) \to -\infty$ ; so $\sin(x) \log(\sin(x)) $ is in indeterminant form as it is in $0 \times - \infty$ ; but in the answer you have written $\sin(x) \log(\sin(x)) \to 0$ ..... How?

Comment: @Suresh As I've explained here above it is a standard limit, indeed take $e^y=\frac1x \to \infty$ for $x\to 0^+$ and we have $x\log x=-\frac{y}{e^y}\to 0$